# A generalization of the Lester circle theorem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I found a conjectures of generalization of the Lester circle theorem a more than year ago, but I no a found solution for the conjectures.  I'm an electrical engineer, I am not a mathematician. I don't know how to prove this result. Could you give a proof?

**[Lester theorem:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lester's_theorem)** Let $ABC$ be a triangle, then the [two Fermat points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point), [the nine-point center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine-point_center), and [the circumcenter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle) [lie on the same circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle).

**A generalization of Lester theorem:** Let $P$ be a point on the [Neuberg cubic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_plane_curve). Let $P_A$ be the reflection of $P$ in line $BC$, and define $P_B$ and $P_C$ cyclically. It is known that the lines $AP_A$, $BP_B$, $CP_C$ concur. Let $Q(P)$ be the point of concurrence. Then [two Fermat points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point), $P$, $Q(P)$ lie on a circle.

When $P=X(3)$ ([X(3)=the circumcenter of the triangle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circumcenter.html)), it is well-know that $Q(P)=Q(X(3))=X(5)$ ([X(5)= the Nine point center of the triangle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Nine-PointCenter.html)), the conjucture becomes Lester theorem. (See 1, 2, 3)

[image]

1-http://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETCPart5.html#X7668

2-https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/AdvancedPlaneGeometry/conversations/topics/2546

3-http://tube.geogebra.org/m/1276919

Comment: You should make this two separate questions.

Comment: Dear @Blue , I thank to You, I will do that in some hour later.

Comment: Dear Mister @Blue , I did